# What are associations between models for?

Tags: extjs, associations, extjs4.2, extjs-stores

What are associations between models for ?

I understand, that they are useful to parse a nested json object from a server, a good example for this is [in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association). But this seems really limited to me.

Are there **other uses** where associations can be used and can simplify programming ?

I think about an example with two grids, where on show the details of the selected row in the other, like a grid of customers, and a grid showing the invoices for the currently selected user.

Comment: yes that is an example, you can use them if you want to connect data together, I don't think that this is a real question, cause you already answered it...

Comment: @Jandalf No, I didn't answer. The question is **Are there other uses ?**. And if the example with the two grids is an example for an association, I cannot find any trace in the docs how this could be implemented through associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer the question with the grid:

you need to set up a [`HasMany`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany)-association between the customer and invoices model. each defined with its own proxy. you will create two stores and bind them to the grids but only load the customers store.

in the grid `select` listener you will do something like this:

```
select: function( rowmodel, record, index, eOpts ) {
    var invoices = record.invoices().load(); // will issue a request on the invoices proxy
    invoicesStore.loadData(invoices);
}
```

**Edit**: example:
[Rules for HasMany Associations in ExtJS](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.de/2012/05/extjs-hasmany-relationships-rules.html)

Comment: This looks promising. I have to drill into it. Would associations also be useful, if the `invoices` store contains already all invoices, but needs to be filtered ?

Comment: look at [`filterProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany-cfg-filterProperty) but I never used it, but it should do what you want.